# What film camera/Polaroid camera is best for a more orange yellow look?

Tags: film, camera, polaroid

What film camera/Polaroid camera is best for warmer orange yellow looking photos? I attached examples of what I'm going for but can't find a camera with a warmer tint, a 1960-70s vibe.

Comment: No attachments are showing. Can you provide a link? Someone with sufficient reputation here will edit it into your question.

Comment: I suggest you use a filter or use a digital camera and manually bias the white balance. In the film days, there are only 1 or 2 white balance presets: sunlight/flash and tungsten and no auto/variable white balance, so if you use sunlight film in the afternoon, you get a yellow hint. Way easier and controllable to use glass or digital filter.

Comment: @user3528438 Just to point out that film has only *one* "preset" and no white balance setting at all is available - film type was the while balance.   You need to choose a specific film and a specific filter combination with appropriate lighting to get a specific look in film (unless you scan it and digitally edit the resulting file).

Comment: Lomography has a large selection of esoteric films and cameras. https://shop.lomography.com/en/films  https://shop.lomography.com/en/cameras

Comment: Have you tried an orange filter?  Some Polaroid cameras came with a filter kit.

Answer (score 5):

**With any type of color photography, the most important thing that will influence the color "look" of your images is the type of light that is illuminating your subject or scene.** If you want photos to have a "warmer" look, then use warmer lighting, such as tungsten bulbs, to illuminate your subjects.

But sometimes you don't have control of the lighting, such as when shooting outdoors during daylight hours. You then must work with the light you have (though you can use colored reflectors located just outside the edge of the camera's view to locally alter the color cast of the light on a specific area in the photo that is near the camera).

**Apart from the light source itself, when using analog film to do photography color is almost all about the specific film you choose to put in the camera and then how that film is developed and prints made from it, not the camera itself.**

If you have a 35mm film camera, you can load any type of 35mm film into it. In some cases which lens you select can have a small effect on the color in an image, but this is much less significant than the film itself. Some films are "warmer" and emphasize the orange, yellow and red hues. Others are "cooler" and concentrate on green and blue hues.

**When using instant cameras, such as Polaroid or Fuji Instax cameras, your choices with regard to film are much more limited.** To alter color significantly using those types of cameras, you can use colored filters in front of the lens. If you are shooting in an environment where you control the light, such as in an indoor photo studio, then you can also place colored filters over your lighting.

Of course, you can also use colored filters on the lens and/or on your lights when shooting 35mm film as well.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on a lot of factors, and the less important, and someone said before, is the camera. But the most important factor should be to know what do you exactly want.

Want that stupid look that most films do when they are on Mexico?

[image]

Well, no need even to use film camera. That's mainly color corrections made in post. So I would discard using any film camera at all since it's just waste of time and money.

But I guess and hope this isn't your aim.

Do you want that hipster, vintage expired film picture?

[image]

Well this is just made using expired film. But results won't be necessary orange. Using expired film just gives random results, and mostly tend to greenish than to yellowish.

Wanna keep it hipster but have some control over it?

[image]

[Préstamos rápidos](https://www.top5credits.com/es/articulos/los-5-mejores-prestamos-online-rapidos-2020/)

This is probably what you want, so just try to use 35mm film like Lomography Redscale XR 50-200 35 mm.

Comment: The other thing that makes that second picture warmer is likely that it is a print which has faded over the years.  OP could probably make a print today and have it look like that in 2065 just by waiting...